# ORDER BY and UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm trying to union two queries and then order by a column. However, whenever I try and run the query it gives an error that doesn't make sense to me.

Example data

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    Company_code    VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    operating_year  INT          NOT NULL,
    Profit          INT          NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (Company_code, operating_year, Profit)
VALUES  ('A', 1999, 2000),
        ('A', 2000, 3000),
        ('B', 1999, 1600),
        ('B', 2000, 4000);
```

Query

```
SELECT 
    t.company_code,
    t.profit
FROM
    test t
WHERE
    t.company_code = 'A'

UNION

SELECT
    t.company_code,
    t.profit
FROM
    test t
WHERE
    t.company_code = 'B'

ORDER BY
--    t.profit; --- Does *not* work
--    profit;   --- Does work
```

Ignore the very basic example, and how just adding an OR to the WHERE statement resolves this.

My question is why does having an alias in the `ORDER BY` throw an error when a `UNION` is involved. But not when run individually?

Comment: you make a new virtual table with the union, which is not t any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why does having an alias (`t`) in the `ORDER BY` throw an error when a `UNION` is involved. But not when run individually.

When you use a set-theoretic operator between two queries (e.g. `UNION`, `UNION ALL`, `EXCEPT`, `INTERSECT`, etc) the `ORDER BY` clause now applies to the *end result* of that operator, which is a new *anonymous* derived-table. So there's no way to bind `t` in `ORDER BY` because it is now out-of-scope.

If you add parentheses around the derived-tables it's easier to see why... so your query is really like this pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT
    company_code,
    profit
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t.company_code,
            t.profit
        FROM
            test t
        WHERE
            t.company_code = 'A'
    ) AS q1

    UNION

    (
        SELECT 
            t.company_code,
            t.profit
        FROM
            test t
        WHERE
            t.company_code = 'B'
    ) AS q2
ORDER BY
    t.profit <-- `t` is not in scope. It's masked by (or "buried inside"?) q1 and q2.
    profit   <-- this works because `profit` is in the result of the UNION
```

Comment: I would add that the `ORDER BY` applies to the combined query and the expressions in it are in a different namespace (not the individual query namespaces anymore).

Comment: Thank you for that, both answers are correct, but this has a bit more thorough detail.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not sorting the separate queries that reference columns through a table alias. You are ordering the UNION query output which is almost like a table itself.

The `ORDER BY` is performed after the `UNION` this is equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
    t.company_code,
    t.profit
    FROM test t
    WHERE t.company_code = 'A'
    UNION
    SELECT
    t.company_code,
    t.profit
    FROM test t
    WHERE t.company_code = 'B'
) t
ORDER BY t.profit; --- Should work
--ORDER BY profit; --- Does work
```